# "where" in eloquent query, joined 3 tables

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have three tables which I have joined using eloquent, the query looks like this

```
    $truck = TCategory::with('truck_categories.touch_points')->get();


    if(count($truck) > 0) {
        return response()->json(array('result' => $truck));
    } else {
        return response()->json(array('result' => 'No Trucks.'));
    }
```

and the response is this:

```
{
"result": [{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "western",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "truck_categories": [{
        "id": 9,
        "touch_point_id": 8,
        "t_category_id": 6,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "touch_points": {
            "id": 8,
            "brand_id": 1,
            "user_id": 11,
            "base_latitude": 3.104193,
            "base_longitude": 101.610487,
            "name": "testing ok",
            "approved": 1,
            "driver": null,
            "created_at": "2018-04-25 07:43:49",
            "updated_at": "2018-04-25 07:45:27",
            "menu_id": 1,
            "location": "Kelana Jaya, 47300 Petaling Jaya, Selangor, Malaysia",
            "service_on_off": 1,
            "slug": "testing-ok",
            "image": null,
            "position": {
                "lat": 3.104193,
                "lng": 101.610487
            }
        }
    }]
}, ...
```

the touch_points appear inside truck_categories, I wanna put a where condition in the query, can someone help me with that?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can put where condition like below:**

```
$truck = TCategory::with(['truck_categories.touch_points' => function($query){
                          $query->where('<Put your condition here>');
                        }])->get();

if(count($truck) > 0) {
    return response()->json(array('result' => $truck));
} else {
    return response()->json(array('result' => 'No Trucks.'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i used it and got this error
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

query:
 $truck = TCategory::with('truck_categories.touch_points',function($query){
            $query->where('name', 'testing ok');
        })->get();

"where" applies to which table?